# ActiveProvider for Device Detection returning null

Tags: device-detection

I am trying to detect device through code but it's not working. However, my device based personalization is working fine. I've enabled device detection in config file already. I can see files under /app_data/devicedetection also. I am using below code to find the device:

```
var deviceProvider = FiftyOne.Foundation.Mobile.Detection.WebProvider.ActiveProvider;

        if (deviceProvider != null)
        {
            var result = deviceProvider.Match(Request.UserAgent);
            vm.IsMobile = result["IsMobile"].ToString().ToLower() == "true";
        }
```

I always get null in deviceProvider variable.

Are there any other approaches that I can follow to detect the device?

Comment: Sitecore provides API reference for the Device Detection service - https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/90/sitecore-experience-manager/en/api-reference-for-the-device-detection-service.html   You can try below sample code - 
`var deviceCache = new DeviceDetectionCache();
var device = deviceCache.GetDeviceInformation(Request.UserAgent)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've used below code and it's working fine:

```
 var deviceInfo = DeviceDetectionManager.GetDeviceInformation(Request.UserAgent);
  var myDevice = deviceInfo.DeviceType;
```